# Keeping db structure and procs in sync

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, copy, smo

I am trying to setup a test database for automated tests to run against.  I know ideally we should be using mock objects, but this is an old app and doing so isn't as easy as it should be.  There's simply too much logic in the database.

Anyhow, enough backstory.  I'm getting a clean db setup that the tests can load with known data so that results are thus known as well.

At the start of the test, a .sql script will be run to empty the tables and then fill them with test data.  The problem I see, is not so much keeping the database structures in sync, as they don't change much (though that would be nice too) but to move all the procs/functions etc across from dev into test at the start of the test.

Is there SQL commands that can be executed to do this?  To read a proc from the dev db, and copy it to the test db?

EDIT: I've actually found that using SQL Management Objects works pretty good.

The only problem is that if someone renamed an item, internal references aren't updated by sql server, and it's created under the old name.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are the two servers linked?  Or are both databaes on the same server?  In other words, can we assume that one SQL script has access to both databases?

Comment: Same server, different databases.

Comment: Rename operations use sp_rename which does not fire any DDL triggers, so there's no easy way to log these.  But based on what you're trying to accomplish, why not just `DROP` **all** of the functions/procedures in the test database before copying from the dev database?

Comment: @Aaron, the test db is empty, but what happens is because the rename doesn't fix the underlying issues.  When you script out the proc "newname", it's created as the oldname.  Really dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SMO, the following works great! And copies in ~40 seconds.

```
    private static void CopyDBSchema(string sourceDBServer, string sourceDBName, string targetDBServer, string targetDBName)
    {
        Server server = new Server(sourceDBServer);
        server.SetDefaultInitFields(true);

        Database db = server.Databases[sourceDBName];
        Transfer t = new Transfer()
        {
            Database = db,

            CopyData = false,
            CopyAllObjects = false,
            CopyAllUsers = false,
            CopyAllLogins = false,

            CopySchema = true,
            CopyAllTables = true,
            CopyAllViews = true,
            CopyAllStoredProcedures = true,
            CopyAllDatabaseTriggers = true,
            CopyAllUserDefinedAggregates = true,
            CopyAllUserDefinedDataTypes = true,
            CopyAllUserDefinedFunctions = true,
            CopyAllUserDefinedTypes = true,

            DropDestinationObjectsFirst = true,
            UseDestinationTransaction = true,
            DestinationServer = targetDBServer,
            DestinationDatabase = targetDBName
        };

        t.Options.WithDependencies = true;
        t.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = true;
        t.Options.DriPrimaryKey = true;
        t.Options.DriForeignKeys = true;
        t.Options.DriIndexes = true;
        t.Options.DriNonClustered = true;
        t.Options.DriUniqueKeys = true;
        t.Options.DriAllKeys = true;
        t.Options.Triggers = true;

        t.TransferData();
        server = null;
    }
```

Comment: Actually, it's copying everything except the keys don't have identity set for some reason.

Comment: Needed to apply a Service Pack

Answer (score 3):

You said that keeping "database structures" in synch wasn't a problem but then you go on to say you needed to move procs/functions from dev to test. These are part of the database structure! IAC, I would suggest a tool like Red-Gate's SQL Compare. It will move any database structure that exists on dev that doesn't exist on test. Very nice tool. I've used it for years.

Comment: @Randy, when I said "structure" I meant "table structure".  And we have SQL Compare, it works great.  But I want to automate this ability.  I don't want to have to know to run the tool before each run of the tests to check if the database structures are the same.  I would like this check handled in .NET code ideally by calling a proc that copies procs from 1 db to another.

Comment: @Chad - were you aware that SQL Compare can be run from the command line, and therefore, in an automated fashion?

Comment: @Randy - it's not installed everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Chad, I'm not sure how automated your looking to get with this. If you wanted to script all the procs at once you can do it from SQL enterprise manager.

Before each test script all the procs from Dev for CREATE. Drop your procs in TEST and run the script from the dev file. That will make sure your procs are in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick-and-dirty SQL script you can use to copy stored procedures from one database to another:

```
USE DestinationDatabase

GO

DECLARE
    @SchemaName sysname,
    @ProcName nvarchar(4000),
    @ProcDefinition nvarchar(max),
    @DropSql nvarchar(4000)

SET @SchemaName = 'dbo'

DECLARE crProcedures CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT r.ROUTINE_NAME, r.ROUTINE_DEFINITION
    FROM SourceDatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Routines r
    WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName
    AND ROUTINE_NAME IN ('Procedure1', 'Procedure2', 'Procedure3')
OPEN crProcedures
FETCH NEXT FROM crProcedures INTO @ProcName, @ProcDefinition
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @DropSql = 'IF  EXISTS ' +
        '(SELECT * FROM sys.objects ' +
        'WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + @ProcName + ''') ' +
        'AND type in (N''P'', N''PC'')) ' +
        'DROP PROCEDURE ' + @ProcName
    EXEC sp_executesql @DropSql
    EXEC sp_executesql @ProcDefinition

    FETCH NEXT FROM crProcedures INTO @ProcName, @ProcDefinition
END
CLOSE crProcedures
DEALLOCATE crProcedures
```

Just make sure you don't confuse the `SourceDatabase` and `DestinationDatabase`, otherwise you'll be in trouble!